# Get var in jQuery(aspx) from (aspx.cs)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this function on aspx(html)

```
<body onload="NewPage2()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function NewPage2() {
            var url = getUrlVars(url);
            document.getElementById("HiddenField1").Value = url["access_token"];
        }
</script>
    <div class = content>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:HiddenField id="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value=""/>
         </form>
        CODE1: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="#CC0000" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

how can I get the var(on jquery(html)) to my variableURL2 in aspx.cs?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string code = HiddenField1.Value;

    Label1.Text = code;

    saveToken(token, code);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have one server hidden control in .aspx page

```
<asp:HiddenField Id="HiddenField1" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

in browser it will be rendered like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="HiddenField1" />
```

assign values from javascript

```
document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "your values here";
```

in aspx.cs render like this

```
  string variableURL2 =   HiddenField1.Value;
```

Comment: Don't wotk, i need do something else?

Comment: i update my code, and i can't get to my var the  HiddenField1.Value;

Comment: @kaub0st3r hav u checked the value after this? `document.getElementById("HiddenField1").Value`

Comment: I have values! I think the problem is in the processing times, i means, first process the aspx.cs(Page_Load()) and after my querie. You know another way to make this? I need execute the jquerie and save the value to a DB. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use server control HiddenField
First you have to add control in your aspx/ascx/master file

```
<asp:HiddenFiled ID="hdn" runat="server"/>
```

Then you can use this control in JS

```
function end(url) {
var url = getUrlVars(url);
var url2 = url["access_token"];
<%= hdn.ClientId %>.value = url["access_token"];
}
```

in code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string variableURL2 = hdn.Value;
}
```

Comment: hdn.ClientId, this ClientId what is?  I tryng but I error on hdn.Value;  (hdn)

Comment: @kaub0st3r if you use ASP.NET controls, typically their IDs change when the control is rendered. That is how you get the actual ID sent to the client, so you can find the control by ID in javascript.

Comment: you have to create control object in your aspx page by write this code<asp:HiddenFiled ID="hdn" runat="server"/>

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this, and both would have to be from a post back since the javascript is fired after the page loads.

redirect and append to the query string, then read it from c#

javascript:
location.href = "/mypage.aspx?variable2=VARFROMJAVASCRIPT";

c#
string variable2 = Request.QueryString["variable2"];

or set the value to a hidden field like above

javascript:
var $hiddenInput = $('',{type:'hidden',id:'variable2',value:'VARFROMJAVASCRIPT'});
$hiddenInput.appendTo('body');

c#
string variable2 = Request["variable2"];

Answer (score 0):

.aspx:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="HiddenField1" runat="server" value=""/>
```

javascript:

```
function end(url) {
            var url = getUrlVars(url);
            var url2 = url["access_token"];
            document..getElementById("HiddenField1").value = url2;
            }
```

.cs file:

```
string variableURL2 = HiddenField1.Value;
```